# Cannot get text from td (ASP.NET MVC )

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have table that display via Razor syntax

Here is code

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="point">
            @(rowNo += 1)
        </td>
        <td class="title">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date_of_Birthday)
        </td>
        <td id="name" class="title">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td class="title"></td>
        <td class="title"></td>
        <td class="title"></td>
        <td style="text-align: end;">
           <img id="delete_pt" src="~/images/icons8-Delete-50.png"/>
            <img src="~/images/doc-50.png"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I try to get value of

```
<td id="name" class="title">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
</td>
```

Via JS

Here is code

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '#delete_pt', function () {
    var title = $(this).find('#name').html();
    console.log(title);
});
```

But when I click I'm not get value it's empty. Where is my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your element with `id="delete_pt"` is an `<img>` and it does not contain any child elements. You need to find the parent `<tr>` element and then find the `<td id="name">` element.

```
$(document).on('click', '#delete_pt', function () {
    var title = $(this).closest('tr').find('#name').html();
    console.log(title);
});
```

However you loop is generating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html. You need to replace your `id` attributes with class names, for example

```
<td class="name title">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
</td>
....
<img class="delete_pt"  src="~/images/icons8-Delete-50.png" />
```

and then use

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete_pt', function () {
    var title = $(this).closest('tr').find('.name').html();
    console.log(title);
});
```

Comment: It works, But I get it with html and I need get only value

Comment: Then use `.text()`

Comment: What??? `DispalyFor()` just outputs text (unless you have a custom `DisplayTemplate` and you have not indicated that in your question!)

Comment: Look I use this one in view for table `https://pastebin.com/H8FRsXTC` aтв this one for getting text and send it to back-end `https://pastebin.com/0YraznKr` and I get it like this `https://imgur.com/a/oYEbA`

Comment: Your 3rd image is just telling your that the jquery script is not loaded, and the 2nd error (500 - Internal Server Error) is because your controller code is throwing an exception

Comment: Yes, but if you can see I get text with some extra spaces

Comment: Or it's not a problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154312/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-mark-spencer).

Answer (score 0):

i believe you need to change it to

```
@Html.DisplayFor(item=> item.Date_of_Birthday)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the item.name as a value to the js

```
<img id="delete_pt" src="~/images/icons8-Delete-50.png" onclick="deletePT(@item.Name)"/>
```

and add a function to yout JS:
(remove the onclick event)

```
function deletePT(itemname){
console.log(itemname);
}
```

Your code generate a ID value to more then one element in the HTML - that is not good. but this is not the issue of the problem

Comment: did you found an answer?